# APT Error: Depends: perl (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1 is to be installed

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apt

I just try install libperl-dev with apt on Ubuntu, but I have following error:

```
user@comp-2:~$ sudo apt-get install libperl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libperl-dev : Depends: perl (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libperl5.14 (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to google the problem but didn't found something clear.
Can some one explain me what it's mean: "Depends: libperl5.14 (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1 is to be installed", and how to solve it?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the error message tells you all three packages (libperl-dev, perl and libperl5.14) need to have exactly the same version (either 5.14.2-6ubuntu2 or 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1), but you are trying to mix the two. I can't tell you why is that (maybe you are trying to mix packages from different distributions, something like debian testing/unstable), but if you used aptitude, you could examine the situation in an interactive dependency solver (maybe it would even find an acceptable solution for you automatically).

So, use aptitude and examine the versions of the packages, both those you are trying to install and those you already have.

Comment: Can you give me some link to read about interactive dependency solver?

Comment: After all I just downloaded package from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/libperl-dev/5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1 can I set this site as repository for apt?

Answer (score 0):

No direct answer to your question but a way to avoid it occurring:

You should not fiddle around with your systems Perl to much. Because a lot of system-packages depend on the systems Perl. If you screw this up, your system might run into troubles.

If you want to be flexible with Perl installations always use Perlbrew! Go to this site, it is very easy: http://perlbrew.pl/ Perlbrew manages different Perls, and all is safely in your $home. (Perlbrew is also on CPAN or available as .deb package, but use the website above, it is saver)

If you then add this line to your .bashrc

```
# Perl is always from perlbrew!
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

You can use the perlbrew commands on your terminal to easily switch between Perl installations.

Maybe this helps you?
Regards

Comment: This is misleading as hell. At least on Debian (and I believe Ubuntu should be similar in this regard), perl is not an essential package and none of the system packages depend on it. Second, suggesting installing a second perl when the user apparently needs just to update his distro packages, is just off topic.